# Slow keyboard/select picker to respond in cordova 4 iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Working on a couple apps, i've noticed recently the first time you interact with a text box or select tag, the keyboard/picker is slow to respond. After that, it's fine for the rest of the session. I saw something about changing the viewport, but that didn't fix it for me.

Loaded up an older application we built in the fall, and it seems to suffer the same problem. It did not when working on in fall/early winter.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with Cordova 4.2.1 and 4.3.0 with platform ios 3.7.0.

[Platform ios 3.8.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/02/25/cordova-ios-3.8.0.html) correct this problem.

But they don't correct [one bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898012/cordova-4-3-0-build-command-returns-error-cannot-find-module-q) : Error: Cannot find module 'Q'

You need [this patch](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/ed272032878959c90eb28ccc1490e96fb7b69287). Don't forget to change 2 files :

- platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-devices
- platforms/ios/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably have to wait until those fixes are in NPM. Given i work with various team members, it would be an issue for all of us to add those manually. Could potentially just do it for release builds.